# Stretching an image as background in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background

I am trying to stretch an image to the boundaries of the browser in IE8.  It is working except the right, left, top, and bottom have white space about the size of 5px.  I want the image to stetch COMPLETELY to all sides.  My employer has hinted that this is the last straw if I can't get this page right :(  Please help if you can..

HTML:

```
</head>
 <body class="fullbackground">
 <!--THIS IS THE BACKGROUND IMAGE--><img class="fullbackground" src="c:\documents and settings\zx08067\Desktop\Outage_Page\background.png">
    <div class="top">
...
...
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position:relative;
}

img.fullbackground {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%; /* alternative: right:0; */
    height:100%; /* alternative: bottom:0; */
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Nice place to work if he's wanting that bad that a website works in IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your css add

```
html,body{
padding:0 0 0 0;
margin:0 0 0 0;
overflow-x:hidden; // To remove the bottom scrollbar
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: That worked, but now it created a new issue.  THere is a scrollbar at the bottom and I can move the page slightly from left to right.  Do you know how I would solve this?

Comment: can you simulate your problem on jsbin.com.

Comment: I can't because this is my company computer and it won't let me access that site.

Comment: But keep in mind that now a user will never be able to scroll horizontally, even if the browser window is less wide than the content you have.  (Or am I wrong?)

Comment: @Arpit Ah, ok. Just wanted to let the OP know too, so he does not have the problem later on. Maby then he would be interested in an other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the body tag to have a margin and padding of 0.

```
body {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Most web browsers have there own default styles on elements. Personally I always use a reset script like:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: That worked, but now it created a new issue. THere is a scrollbar at the bottom and I can move the page slightly from left to right. Do you know how I would solve this?